# AttributeError: module 'sst' has no attribute 'train_reader'

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, sst

I am very new to sentiment analysis. Trying to use Stanford Sentiment Treebank(sst) and ran into an error.

```py
from nltk.tree import Tree
import os
import sst
trees = "C:\\Users\m\data\trees"
tree, score = next(sst.train_reader(trees))
```

[Output]:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-4101f90b0b16> in <module>()
----> 1 tree, score = next(sst.train_reader(trees))

AttributeError: module 'sst' has no attribute 'train_reader'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for https://github.com/JonathanRaiman/pytreebank, not https://pypi.org/project/sst/.

On the python side, that error is pretty clear. Once you import the right package, though, I'm not sure I saw `train_reader` but I could be wrong.

UPDATE:
I'm not entirely sure why you're running into the 'sst' not having the attribute train_reader. Make sure you didn't accidentally install the 'sst' package if you're using conda. It looks like the 'sst' is referring to a privately created module and that one **should work.**

I got your import working but what I did was I:

1. Installed everything specified in the `requirements.txt` file.
2. `import sst` was still giving me an error so I installed nltk and sklearn to resolve that issue. (fyi, im not using conda. im just using pip and virtualenv for my own private package settings. i ran `pip install nltk` and `pip install sklearn`)
3. At this point, `import sst` worked for me.

Comment: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cgpotts/cs224u/blob/2019-spring/sst_01_overview.ipynb

Comment: I wanted to replicate the code in the above jupyter notebook. In there "import sst" is used. Other than the method you suggested is there a way to replicate what is done in the notebook?

Comment: @moli see if my updated post helps you out. if it wasn't the answer, im hoping it at least guides you. another suggestion is to try to re-read and carefully follow the instructions on that guide step-by-step.

Comment: I have sklearn and nltk installed now I'm getting an error AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'safe_macro_f1'. I have uninstalled utils packages but still does not work still getting the same error :(

Comment: yay, we're making progress! sorry, im at work right now so i probably can't look at this till later today. maybe try tackling it yourself for now? my guess is you're at a university so id recommend just sitting down with someone who already has this working if that's possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! The problem is solved!! :-)

Comment: nice! best of luck to ya

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're importing the sst package selenium-simple-test, which is not what you're looking for.

Try sst.discover() , if you get the error

```
TypeError: discover() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'test_loader', 'package', 'dir_path', and 'names'
```

You are using the selenium-simple-test package

Comment: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cgpotts/cs224u/blob/2019-spring/sst_01_overview.ipynb

Comment: How does "import sst" work out in this jupyter notebook and how can I do the same thing?